# Is there a way to get the missing End Exit Gateway Portal back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

At some point the exit gateway portal (the small portal you come out of nearer the outer islands in the End) in my single player (survival) minecraft world has gone missing.  If I go through the entrance portal I come out over the void and have to activate flight mode to avoid dying.  I also have to fly all the way to aproximately 0,0 when I want to leave the End.   This is not a problem but I would like to restore the exit portal if it's possible to do so.  I know minecraft has a lot of 'tricks' that take advantage of game mechanics so I was wondering if there was one for restoring that gateway portal (or make a new one)

It may be something I've done (Over time I've removed region files, but I can't recall if I removed any End region files before this happened)

Comment: If you are ok with activating cheats, build an End portal in the End.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're asking about how to fix or replace your End gateway portal.

The first couple times when you revive the Ender dragon and kill it, a new End gateway portal will appear at the edge of the main End island.

On Java Edition, 20 End gateways are the limit that can appear in a given world, and on other versions of MineCraft it's even less.

Comment: The 'entrance' end gateway portal is intact.  It's the other end of that portal that's missing.    I assume you're saying that the solution is to kill the dragon again to get a new pair of end gateway portals.

Comment: @MrVimes That's probably the best option. Sure you could rebuild the return portal in creative mode, but there's no vanilla survival way to restore it. OTOH there are many randomly spawned return portals all over the End, just find one near to the exit and use it to return.

Comment: I didn't know about the randomly spawned return portals.  I'll look for one of those.  Thanks.